# does native-base have a utility method that allows us to extract computed theme data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, native-base

I am using native base and I want to use some of the theme values for example the `primary` text color and the main background color

I am looking for something that can take in a `theme` object as a parameter so I don't need to be in the context yet.  So I can't use `useTheme()`

something along the lines of

```
computeStyle('Text', { colorScheme: 'primary' }, theme);
```

The second parameter being props that are applied to Text that may alter the result

The result should have a type of  `TextStyle | ViewStyle`

The tricky bit I found so far is I don't have the theme context as of yet.